# Why would my book say that Integer's compareTo has an Object parameter?

Tags: java, generics, integer, comparable

I'm preparing for the AP Computer Science Exam and I'm confused by my text's discussion of the `Integer` class.

The text defines `Integer`'s `compareTo` as follows:

```
 int compareTo(Object other)
```

It made since to me at first that it would have an `Object` parameter because I thought that was the only way it could implement `Comparable`. However, I ended up looking at the `Integer` class in Eclipse and I noticed that it uses generics for `Comparable` and thus defines `compareTo` with an `Integer` parameter.

Is this a mistake in my book? It led me to believe that it was casting the `Object` to an `Integer` in the method, which is wrong (and makes a difference on the exam). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you add more context to the book quote?

Comment: Please update your resources. At least look for Java SE 6 compliant tutorials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was how the code looked in pre-Java 5 versions, when generics were not there. This also shows that the book you're referring is toooooo old. Please avoid.

Comment: Even with generics the underlying type is `Object`. Generics just adds compile type checking.